# google-maps-react get marker position on drag end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the marker position when the marker is dragged. I found this : [Drag marker event with callback providing lat/long?](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/39)

and implemented on my app like so:

```
export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  onMarkerDragEnd = evt => {
    console.log(evt);
  };

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: "100%",
      height: "300px"
    };

    let lat = this.props.lat;
    let lng = this.props.lng;

    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        style={style}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng
        }}
        zoom={14}
      >
        <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          draggable={true}
          onDragend={this.onMarkerDragEnd}
          name={"Current location"}
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

the onMarkerDragEnd functions logs an evt object like this:

```
{onClick: undefined, draggable: true, onDragend: ƒ, name: 
"Currentlocation", map: Zf, …}
draggable: true
google:{maps: {…}}
map: Zf {gm_bindings_: {…}, __gm: uf, gm_accessors_: {…}, mapTypeId: 
"roadmap", center: _.K, …}
mapCenter:{lat: "37.122024", lng: "25.234458"}
name:"Current location"
onClick:undefined
onDragend:ƒ (evt)
__proto__:Object
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
onMarkerDragEnd = (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.google.maps.Marker.getPosition().lat());
}
```

but it return can't get position of undefined

So how do i get the position of the marker from this returned event? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The third argument to the `onDragend` event listener function contains the coordinates of the marker after the drag.

**Example**

```
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    markers: [
      {
        name: "Current position",
        position: {
          lat: 37.77,
          lng: -122.42
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  onMarkerDragEnd = (coord, index) => {
    const { latLng } = coord;
    const lat = latLng.lat();
    const lng = latLng.lng();

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const markers = [...this.state.markers];
      markers[index] = { ...markers[index], position: { lat, lng } };
      return { markers };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "300px"
        }}
        zoom={14}
      >
        {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
          <Marker
            position={marker.position}
            draggable={true}
            onDragend={(t, map, coord) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(coord, index)}
            name={marker.name}
          />
        ))}
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use onDragEnd if onDragend is not working for you. onDragEnd worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Above answers not worked for me because `onDragEnd` returning `undefined` in my case.

```
onDragend={(t, map, coord) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(coord, index)}
```

So I find `coordinates` by using below line

```
onDragEnd={(e) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
```

You can find it here (**Draggable Markers**)

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps

**Simple Example**

**State**

```
state = {
    region: {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }
}
```

**Marker**

```
<Marker
      coordinate={this.getMapRegion()}
      draggable={true}
      onDragEnd={(e) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
      title={ "Location"}
  />
```

**onMarkerDragEnd**

```
onMarkerDragEnd = (coord) => {
    let newRegion = {
      latitude: parseFloat(coord.latitude),
      longitude: parseFloat(coord.longitude),
      latitudeDelta: 0.0522,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0321,
    };
    this.setState({
      region: newRegion,
    });
  };
```

Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

i have a simple solution

```
<GoogleMapReact
 bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: '' }}
 defaultCenter={this.state.center}
 defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
 yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
 onClick = {this.changeMarkerPosition}
>
```

then in the function

```
  changeMarkerPosition =(e)=>{
    this.setState({
    ...this.state,
      details:{
        ...this.state.details,
        lat:e.lat,
        lng:e.lng
      }
    })
  }
```

this will automatically give the latest co-ordinates and u can move ur marker accordingly by binding it to state.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that onDragEnd does not work for me. Instead I needed to use onDragend with a lowercase e for the marker event as in:

```
<Marker
        position={marker.position}
        draggable={true}
        onDragend={(t, map, coord) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(coord, index)}
        name={marker.name}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Complete Solution** 
>   **getLocation()** function initially get the current location and set on the map.
>   **onMarkerDragEnd()** function get the marker location when we drag to another place.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';

class Maps extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            markers: [
                {
                    name: "Current position",
                    position: {
                        lat: '24.914161699999998',
                        lng: '67.082216'
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    }

    onMarkerDragEnd = (coord, index) => {
        const { latLng } = coord;
        const lat = latLng.lat();
        const lng = latLng.lng();

        this.setState(prevState => {
            const markers = [...this.state.markers];
            markers[index] = { ...markers[index], position: { lat, lng } };
            return { markers };
        });
    }

    getLocation = () => {
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
                const coords = pos.coords;

                let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
                newState.markers[0].position.lat = coords.latitude;
                newState.markers[0].position.lng = coords.longitude;

                this.setState(newState);
                console.log("map", this.state.markers[0].position.lat, this.state.markers[0].position.lng)
            });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLocation()
    }

    handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const location = {
            latitude: this.state.markers[0].position.lat,
            longitude: this.state.markers[0].position.lng
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <Map
                    google={this.props.google}
                    style={{
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "300px"
                    }}
                    zoom={14}
                    initialCenter={{ lat: this.state.markers[0].position.lat, lng: this.state.markers[0].position.lng }}
                >
                    {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
                        <Marker
                            key={index}
                            position={marker.position}
                            draggable={true}
                            onDragend={(t, map, coord) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(coord, index)}
                            name={marker.name}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Map>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'google api key here'
})(Maps);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
centerMoved(mapProps, map) {
        console.log('args:', mapProps, map);
        console.log(map.getCenter().lat());
}
```