# react google maps find midpoint

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am using the @react-google-maps/api package. I get the midpoint with onCenterChanged. My problem here is that every time the user drags it gives me the midpoint. Is it possible for me to get the midpoint as soon as the user releases their drag? I will send a fetch request and get results. According to the current system, it constantly sends requests in each movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. The dragend event completely solved my problem. see: [google-maps-react get marker position on drag end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495060/google-maps-react-get-marker-position-on-drag-end)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).